# How do I make a comprehensive guide on a particular topic?

Tags: support

I have just made this self answer : [How does a Bicycle work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/800083/how-does-a-bicycle-work)

It is very much obvious that this question is too broad. But I wish to cover every possible concept about a bicycle in this answer in the near future.

I saw a bicycle question a couple days ago and I had answered it. I was pointed out in the comments that a part of my answer was wrong and upon further research, I verified that my answer was partially wrong and had updated it. I did some more research on many of the topics regarding a bicycle and planned on making this guide.

I have already spent around 3-4 hours on this and willing to spend a lot more time.

What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: … seems to me you want to write a book, not a PSE answer.

Comment: Consider making this a page on your website, or writing a paper for a short-form education journal like _The Physics Teacher_.

Comment: @knzhou. would definitely consider that.

Answer (score 6):

If you look in the [tour page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour), you'll actually see that users should avoid asking (emphasis mine):

> ...Questions with too many possible answers or **that would require an extremely long answer**

Hence, the SE model as a whole isn't intended to provide *comprehensive* answers to subjects, it's intended to provide *specific* answer to *specific* questions. So by design of the site, you are not able to "cover every possible concept about a bicycle in this answer".

It may be possible to break your answers into smaller pieces asked separately, but I suspect a good portion of them would fall afoul of the engineering or homework policies & closed as such.